# Create phonegap project that is NOT named HelloWorld

Tags: android, cordova

I have been trying for at least 2 hours to create a new phonegap project via command line that is NOT named HelloWorld. After finding a myriad of different options/methods I am quite puzzled as to why all phonegap related instructions are either confusing, wrong, or simply do not work.

I followed these instructions here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html (in all variations) but was unsuccessful.

What is the correct way to create a new project with a name of my choosing and set it up to run on Android?

This might seem like an extremely dumb question but I can not even begin to describe the amount of frustration I had so far with trying to use phonegap and any related software. Nothing works as expected and none of the instructions I found anywhere translate to something usable in the real world.

Comment: Sorry you are having problems with the documentation. Cordova is an open source project that Phonegap is built on top of and AFAIK all of the PG documentation is just Cordova documentation. If you are having specific issues it would be very helpful to make a list of these and file documentation bug reports at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB to help other users having the same issues in the future. That said, I've never had a problem with http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface

Comment: There is an open issue on phonegap-cli project: [create name and id params no longer works starting in 3.4.0 #263](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli/issues/263)

Comment: See, there you go. At least I have proof now that I am not stupid and indeed it does not work in the version I am using which is 3.4.0. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure you can

edit your project name in config.xml located in parent folder, not in platform.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.company.YourProjectName" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>YourProjectName</name>
    <description>
        YourProjectName.
    </description>
    <author email="xxxxxxxx@yahoo.com" href="http://revivalx.com">
        Mohammad Nurdin bin Norazan
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
</widget>
```

[image]

then you run `cordova build android`.

Done!!

Comment: Your solution works. Thank you for that. However, I do not understand why phonegap provides command line options that do not work?

Comment: Apparently it does not work otherwise I wouldn't have come here to find a solution. Also see the but posted here: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli/issues/263

Comment: i found config.xml in 'appname\www' folder. after editing the name and package there it worked fine :)

Comment: This generates an error for ios: xcodebuild: error: The project 'NEWNAME.xcodeproj' does not contain a target named 'NEWNAME'.

Answer (score 6):

This appears to be a bug in version 3.4.0: [create name and id params no longer works starting in 3.4.0 #263](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli/issues/263)

For versions 3.3.x following the steps below should work.

---

## Phonegap CLI - `create`

### Usage:

```
$ phonegap create folder -i com.phonegap.hello-world -n Hello World
```

#### Description:

Creates a new application at the provided path.

The application name and package ID can also be customized.
  These values are set in the app manifest (www/config.xml) and are used when
  creating a native project (platforms/`<platform>`/).

#### Options:

- `--name`, `-n`    *name*         application name (default: "Hello World")
- `--id`, `-i`        *package*    package name (default: "com.phonegap.hello-world")

---

### Example

In this example I'll assume that you have the command line ready to use and pointed to the path (system folder) that you want to create your project.

The symbol `$` indicates the command line.

To create a **MyApp** folder, with **My Fancy App** as application name and **com.apps.myfancyapp** as a package name do as following.

```
$ phonegap create MyApp --id com.apps.myfancyapp --name My Fancy App
```

Use the explicit options `--name` and `--id` or the shorts `-n` and `-i` to avoid mistakes, but if you do, just change the manifest as explained in Description.

Now that we have created the folder and the project files, then do:

```
$ cd MyApp
$ phonegap build android
```

If it's all OK you'll see the following messages in console:

```
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] compiling Android...
[phonegap] successfully compiled Android app
```

---

**NOTE:** You need to have `ANT`, `JAVA_SDK` and the `Android SDK` installed and the environment `PATH` correctly adjusted, or else build will fail.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer but nothing worked. the --name/-n and --id/-i parameters are completely ignored and phonegap keeps creating a standard HelloWorld empty application. I have done this probably a hundred times now in different variations and it simple does not work.

Comment: Which operating system and which version of Node.js are you using? Try to update `Node.js` and then use npm to reinstall or update `Phonegap` and `Ant` to the lastest version. Use the command `npm update -g phonegap` to update Phonegap and `npm update -g ant` to update Ant. If still not worked, you probably have problems with the system `PATH`.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried:

```
cordova create folder_name com.your.application.name-space 'App Name'
```

This is how I start all of my projects.

Comment: I tried it and apparently a project was created with the correct name, however, now the project itself is broken and the "phonegap build android" command tells me project directory could not be found.

Comment: @Flobbo Navigate to your project folder and run "phonegap build android"

Comment: There was something else missing for the build command but after trying so many things I don't remember which step finally fixed that issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy and simple process with reference to window 7.

1. You must have node.js install on you system (You can that by typing npm  in command prompt)
2. You must have install phone gap globally , (If not have yet then run below command in CMD)

   > npm install -g phonegap
3. After installation :
   Just run few commands

   > phonegap create AppFolder com.example.MyApp MyApp

   Now you can check AppFolder is created in your present directory(cmd root directory.)
   Move to AppFolder.

   > cd AppFolder
   >
   > phonegap build android

This will download all necessary file to project directory.
Now you are ready with phoneGap project.

Above description shared is outdated, but useful.For latest go through this [Getting Start with phone gap](http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started/)